# Using a variable to store a filepath and then open, copy, paste & close workbooks with the variable

Tags: excel, vba, variables

So I am trying to give the user the ability to select a file from which I want to import (copy & paste) the contents from worksheets in that file into the current workbook. I have been able to do so by hardcoding the filepath into the code but am having trouble doing the same with a variable to hold the filepath of the selected file before opening, copying, pasting and closing the file. All of the latter works fine, I'm just stuck on the variable part.

Like I said I have been able to do it by hardcoding the filepath into the open & close subs (youll see what i mean in a minute) but dont know how to go about setting and using the variable across different subs

```
Option Explicit
Public InputFile As String

Sub OpenWorkbook()
    'attempt to let the variable equal to the filepath in a cell
    Worksheets("Input_Parameters").Range("F9").Value = InputFile
    'I was able to reference directly the hardcoded filepath here, having an issue with putting it in a variable
    Workbooks.Open InputFile
End Sub

Sub CloseWorkbook()
    'this will need altering also
    Workbooks("InputFile").Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub

Sub SelectInput()
     Dim FileSelect As Variant
     Dim wb As Workbook
     Dim i As Integer
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     FileSelect = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*", _
     MultiSelect:=False)
     If FileSelect = False Then
     MsgBox "Select the file name"
     Exit Sub
     End If
     Worksheets("Input_Parameters").Range("F9").Value = FileSelect
     'attempting to let the value equal a global variable
     Set InputFile = FileSelect
End Sub


Sub Import()
    Dim PRC As String
    PRC = Worksheets("Input_Parameters").Cells(17, "B").Value

OpenWorkbook
'this first reference is what I was playing with, the rest is what worked when hardcoded
Workbooks("InputFile").Worksheets("Run_Map").Range("A2:Z500").Copy _
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Run_Map").Range("A2:Z500")

Workbooks("Mock_OneSourceOfTruth_1.xlsx").Worksheets("Reporting_Map").Range("A2:Z500").Copy _
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reporting_Map").Range("A2:Z500")

Workbooks("Mock_OneSourceOfTruth_1.xlsx").Worksheets("Variable_Map").Range("A2:Z500").Copy _
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Variable_Map").Range("A2:Z500")

Workbooks("Mock_OneSourceOfTruth_1.xlsx").Worksheets("Product_Map_" & PRC).Range("A2:Z500").Copy _
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Product_Map_ETY").Range("A2:Z500")

Workbooks("Mock_OneSourceOfTruth_1.xlsx").Worksheets("Subproduct_Map").Range("A2:Z500").Copy _
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Subproduct_Map").Range("A2:Z500")

Workbooks("Mock_OneSourceOfTruth_1.xlsx").Worksheets("Currency_Map").Range("A2:Z500").Copy _
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Currency_Map").Range("A2:Z500")

Workbooks("Mock_OneSourceOfTruth_1.xlsx").Worksheets("FX_Map").Range("A2:Z500").Copy _
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FX_Map").Range("A2:Z500")

CloseWorkbook
End Sub
```

Im comfortable with all the code and how it works, I just want some guidance about the variables, what ways can I do this? declare the variable globally? how can I do that? any other options? Can I even reference the filepath in the OpenWorkbook() sub as a variable rather than the hardcoded filepath?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to copy data, I find it incredible helpful to stick to concise variable handling, i. e. one variable for the **source**-*whatever* (e. g. workbook, worksheet, range, cell, row index, column index, etc.), and one for the target.

Second, I would recommend to keep variables as private as possible. If you want to communicate a value as a result of `Sub`, change that `Sub` into a `Function` and let the result be the return value of that function.

Lastly, it also helps to keep every subroutine of a macro that is not explicitly meant to be called from other macros as well `Private`, so that every macro has its own separate scope within its module file.

That being said, I think the code you're looking for looks something like this:

```vb
Option Explicit

' Entry point of macro
Sub Import()
    Dim SourceWb As Workbook
    Dim TargetWb As Workbook

    ' Prevents Excel from showing the opening and closing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' The target is this workbook
    Set TargetWb = ThisWorkbook

    ' Let the user select the workbook
    Set SourceWb = OpenSourceWorkbook
    If SourceWb Is Nothing Then
        ' The user has cancelled the selection.
        ' We can be fairly sure they'll assume that clicking "Cancel"
        ' cancels the operation, so we can just exit the macro
        ' without further notice.

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If SourceWb Is TargetWb Then
        MsgBox "Cannot copy from and to the same workbook." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Cancelling the import.", vbExclamation, "Invalid source file"

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Store whether so far everything worked
    Dim Success As Boolean

    ' Copy the desired data, but stop if something goes wrong
    Success = CopyData(SourceWb, TargetWb, "Run_Map", "A2:Z500")
    If Success Then Success = CopyData(SourceWb, TargetWb, "Reporting_Map", "A2:Z500")
    If Success Then Success = CopyData(SourceWb, TargetWb, "Variable_Map", "A2:Z500")
    If Success Then Success = CopyData(SourceWb, TargetWb, "Product_Map_ETY", "A2:Z500")
    If Success Then Success = CopyData(SourceWb, TargetWb, "Subproduct_Map", "A2:Z500")
    If Success Then Success = CopyData(SourceWb, TargetWb, "Currency_Map", "A2:Z500")
    If Success Then Success = CopyData(SourceWb, TargetWb, "FX_Map", "A2:Z500")

    ' Close the user-selected source workbook
    Call SourceWb.Close(SaveChanges:=False)

    If Success Then
        MsgBox "All data was copied successfully.", vbInformation, "Success"
    End If
    ' In the other case we triggered a message box earlier,
    ' so no need to report that again.

    ' Re-enable the screen updating - and we're done!
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function OpenSourceWorkbook() As Workbook
    Dim SelectedFilePath As Variant

    SelectedFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*", _
    MultiSelect:=False)

    If SelectedFilePath = False Then
        ' The user has cancelled the dialog
        ' Set the result to Nothing
        Set OpenSourceWorkbook = Nothing
    Else
        ' Open the file and set it as result
        Set OpenSourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(SelectedFilePath)
    End If

End Function

Private Function CopyData(SourceWb As Workbook, TargetWb As Workbook, _
        WorksheetName As String, Range As String) As Boolean

    Dim SourceWs As Worksheet
    Dim TargetWs As Worksheet
    Dim SourceArea As Range
    Dim TargetArea As Range

    ' Try to obtain the source worksheet
    Set SourceWs = TryGetWorksheetByName(SourceWb, WorksheetName)
    If SourceWs Is Nothing Then
        ' Source worksheet not found. Report error and abort.
        MsgBox "The file you selected does not appear to be a valid source for the data." & vbCrLf & _
            "It does not have a worksheet named '" & WorksheetName & "'." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Cancelling the import.", vbExclamation, "Invalid source file"

        ' Return failure
        CopyData = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Try to obtain the target worksheet
    Set TargetWs = TryGetWorksheetByName(TargetWb, WorksheetName)
    If TargetWs Is Nothing Then
        ' Target worksheet not found. Report error and abort.
        MsgBox "Cannot copy the data to the target workbook since it" & vbCrLf & _
            "does not have a worksheet named '" & WorksheetName & "'." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Cancelling the import.", vbExclamation, "Invalid target file"

        ' Return failure
        CopyData = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Range to copy from and to
    Set SourceArea = SourceWs.Range(Range)
    Set TargetArea = TargetWs.Range(Range)

    ' Finally, copy the data
    Call SourceArea.Copy(Destination:=TargetArea)

    ' Return success
    CopyData = True
End Function

Private Function TryGetWorksheetByName(Wb As Workbook, WorksheetName As String) As Worksheet
    Set TryGetWorksheetByName = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
        Set TryGetWorksheetByName = Wb.Sheets(WorksheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Note: if you want to write a **really** flawless macro in terms of usability, you'd test **all** your a-priori-requirements (i. e. existance of all required worksheets) *before* actually copying any data, so that the macro is either successful or doesn't do anything at all, to prevent from doing stuff halfway. But I guess this was not important in your case since you can always chose to not save or start the import again.